# Interacting with the objects in a list as a whole

Tags: python, oop

I was wondering if there was an easy way to make separate objects, say 3-5 of them, assign them to a list and have that list be able to access the methods from the class those objects came from. I can interact with each individual object and have made a way to interact with the objects as a single group, but my method requires the initialization of each variable's attributes and an interaction with each variable's attributes to be separate.

```
class Critter(object):
    """A virtual pet"""
    def __init__(self, name, hunger = 0, boredom = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.hunger = hunger
        self.boredom = boredom

    def __str__(self):
        rep = "Critter Object\n"
        rep += "name: " + self.name + "\n"
        rep += "hunger level: " + str(self.hunger) + "\n"
        rep += "boredom level: " + str(self.boredom) + "\n"
        return rep

    def __pass_time(self):
        self.hunger += 8
        self.boredom += 8

    @property
    def mood(self):
        unhappiness = self.hunger + self.boredom
        if unhappiness < 5:
            m = "happy"
        elif 5 <= unhappiness <= 10:
            m = "okay"
        elif 11 <= unhappiness <= 15:
            m = "frustrated"
        else:
            m = "mad"
        return m

    def talk(self):
        print("I'm", self.name, "and I feel", self.mood, "now.\n")
        self.__pass_time()

    def eat(self, food):
        self.food = food
        if self.food < 5:
            f = "I'm still very hungry."
            self.hunger -= 1
        elif 5 <= self.food <= 10:
            f = "I'm still a little hungry."
            self.hunger -= 2
        elif 11 <= self.food <= 15:
            f = "I could eat a little more."
            self.hunger -= 4
        else:
            f = "Brruppp. I'm full now, thank you."
            self.hunger -= 8
        print(f)
        if self.hunger < 0:
            self.hunger = 0
        self.__pass_time()

    def play(self, fun):
        self.fun = fun
        if self.fun < 5:
            u = "I want to play some more!"
            self.boredom -= 1
        elif 5 <= self.fun <= 10:
            u = "That was fun."
            self.bordeom -= 2
        elif 11 <= self.fun <= 15:
            u = "That was really fun!."
            self.boredom -= 4
        else:
            u = "Wheee! That was really, really fun!"
            self.boredom -= 8
        print(u)
        if self.boredom < 0:
            self.boredom = 0
        self.__pass_time()

def main():
    crit_name = input("What do you want to name your critter?: ")
    crit = Critter(crit_name)

    choice = None
    while choice != "0":
        print \
        ("""
        Critter Caretaker

        0 - Quit
        1 - Listen to your critter
        2 - Feed your critter
        3 - Play with your critter
        """)

        choice = input("Choice: ")
        print()

        #exit
        if choice == "0":
            print("Good-bye.")

        #listen to your critter
        elif choice == "1":
            crit.talk()

        #feed your critter
        elif choice == "2":
            crit.eat(int(input("How many pounds of food would you like to give to " + crit_name + "? ")))

        #play with your critter
        elif choice == "3":
            crit.play(int(input("How many minutes would you like to play with " + crit_name + "? ")))

        #some unknown choice
        else:
            print(crit)

main()
```

This is what I had before doing anything to complete the following question on my assignment:

**Create a Critter Farm program by instantiating several Critter objects and keeping track of them through a list. Mimic the Critter Caretaker program, but instead of requiring the user to care for a single critter, require them to care for an ENTIRE FARM. Each menu choice should allow the user to perform some action for all of the critters, or listen to all of the critters). To make the program interesting, give each critter random starting hunger and boredom levels.**

What I wanted to do was create 3-5 individual objects, assign them to a list (crit_list=[crit1, crit2, crit3, etc.]), then be able to have that list access the methods in Critter() to interact with each individual object in the list, possibly having them each return a response.

**UPDATE:**
I know have the following code:

```
from random import randint    
....
def main():
    crit_name1=input("What do you want to name your critter?: ")
    crit_name2=input("What do you want to name your critter?: ")
    crit_name3=input("What do you want to name your critter?: ")
    crit_name4=input("What do you want to name your critter?: ")
    crit_name5=input("What do you want to name your critter?: ")
    names=[crit_name1,crit_name2,crit_name3,crit_name4,crit_name5]
    critters=[]
    for name in names:
        critters.append(Critter(name,randint(1,8),randint(1,8)))
....
    choice=None
    while choice!="0":
        print \
        ("""
        Critter Caretaker

        0 - Quit
        1 - Listen to your critter
        2 - Feed your critter
        3 - Play with your critter
        """)

        choice=input("Choice: ")
        print()

        #exit
        if choice=="0":
            print("Good-bye.")

        #listen to your critter
        elif choice=="1":
            for critter in critters:
                critters.talk()

        #feed your critter
        elif choice=="2":
            for critter in critters:
                criters.eat(int(input("How many pounds of food would you like to give to " + crit_name + "? ")))

        #play with your critter
        elif choice=="3":
            for critter in critters:  
                critters.play(int(input("How many minutes would you like to play with " + crit_name + "? ")))

        #some unknown choice
        else:
            for critter in critters:
                print(critter)

main()
```

I can print all of the attributes associated with each object in the critters list, but when I attempt to listen, feed, or play with my critters, I get an error that states:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'play'
```

How do I solve this?

**UPDATE:**
I figured it out. In the for loops for choices 1-3, I used critters.talk(), for example, instead of critter.talk(). It works perfectly now, thanks to those who helped.

Comment: Can you come up with some code? What have you tried already?

Comment: Perhaps what you needs is class methods and class attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the general idea of the approach to take.

```
import .critter
from random import randint

names = ['cat', 'dog', 'goat']

def main():
    critters = []
    for name in names:
        critters.append(critter.Critter(name,randint(1,6),randint(1,6)))
    ...
    print_menu()

    if menu_option == 1:
        for critter in critters:
            # process option 1

    elif menu_option == 2:
        for critter in critters:
            # process option 2
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```